# При переходе на jQuery (3.5.1) ломается ui.dropdownchecklist-1.5

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

При переходе на jQuery (3.5.1) в компоненте ui.dropdownchecklist-1.5, выпадающий список не правильно расчитывает позицию и уходит в левый верхний угол.

````
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"js/ui.dropdownchecklist-1.5/css/ui.dropdownchecklist.themeroller.css\">
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"./js/jquery-3.5.1/jquery-3.5.1.js\"></script>
<!--  <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"./js/jquery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js\"></script> -->
<script language=\"javascript\" src=\"js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js\"></script>
<script language=\"javascript\" src=\"js/ui.dropdownchecklist-1.5/js/ui.dropdownchecklist-1.5-min.js\"></script>
<body>
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>qqq</th>
      <th>www</th>
      <th>
         <select name='xxx' id='xxxID' class='xxxCL'>
            <option value='0'></option>
            <option value='0'>A</option>
            <option value='1'>B</option>
            <option value='2'>C</option>
         </select>
      </th>
   </tr>
</table>
    
</body>
<script>
    $(()=>{
        $('.xxxCL').dropdownchecklist();
    });
</script>```

...есть ли способ при таких версиях jQuery, вернуть работоспособность dropdownchecklist?
В версии **jquery-1.10.1** все работает норм. 
PS. это касается табличной верстки.
````

Comment: Пришлось перейти на рабочий плагин.

Comment: По данному вопросу решение так и не найдено...